# The red vertical line over the entire height of the site. How to remove?

Tags: wordpress

Today on the [site](http://www.AlkoNarkoStop.com.ua) appeared red vertical line along the entire height of the site. Can you please tell how to remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main_color class has the bacgkround image of http://www.alkonarkostop.com.ua/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/-e1423758635687.jpg

removing this in the chrome developer tools removed the vertical line. Try it. If it works for you, you need to check the css and remove this line or remove main_color from your html.